# Magento 2 compilation problems

Tags: magento2.3.4, compilation

I'm having some problems running di:compile, when running it stops at 57% with one error in braintree an braintreegraphql.

Those modules are both disabled, but the problem is still there.
I«m running magento 2.3.4 and all is working but the compilation.

Running compilation:

```
Compilation was started.
Interceptors generation... 4/7 [========>-----] 57% 19 secs 259.0 MiB
In Generator.php line 139:
```

> Class Magento\Braintree\Gateway\Config\Config does not exist
>   Class Magento\BraintreeGraphQl\Model\Resolver\CreateBraintreeClientToken\Interceptor generation error: The requested class did not generate properly,
>   because the 'generated' directory permission is read-only.

If --- after run
ning the `bin/magento setup:di:compile` CLI command when the `generated` di
rectory permission is set to write --- the requested class did not generate
properly, then you must add the generated class object to the signature of
the related construct method, only.

Hope someone can help me, since i found some solutions but none worked..

Thanks in advance,

Best regards,

Leonel Nunes

Comment: i think try this 1. Remove "Generated" folder and clear the "Var" folder.

2. Run the upgrade and deploy commands and then check.

Comment: Hello Mohit Patel, and thanks for the reply. I've already tried that, no luck :S ...Any other idea?

Comment: you are removed Generated folder in magento root and after you removed `rm -rf var/generation/* var/cache/* var/report/* pub/static/frontend/* pub/static/adminhtml/* var/page_cache/* var/di/* generated/*` ???

Comment: Yes, all removed, the folders I have, I don't have var/cache/

Answer (score 0):

the error says

> 'generated' directory permission is read-only

try to set correct permissions for the magento folders

see - https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html#perms-set-two-users

Comment: Hello Denys, thanks for the reply. No the permissions are ok, I've checked that also and remake them, it mention that but it's not the problem,..

Comment: @Denys is right, this is permission issue, it is not recommended but for your testing try to give full permission (777) on generated directory `chmod -R 777 generated/`

Comment: Hello Shoaib, ok, i will try it with permission 777 wish I didn't tested.

Answer (score 0):

in magento forum Mr. Vimal gave the solution, doing this worked:

```
composer update
chmod -R 0777 var/ pub/ generated/
rm -rf var/cache/* var/view_preprocessed/* generated/* pub/static/*
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

`Composer update` was the solution.

Best regards and thanks to all.

Leonel Nunes